# What's the point of the overly complex abduction?

Tags: plot-explanation, 24

I am currently rewatching Season 1 of 24 and while the plot lines around Bauer's daughter Kimberly and his wife Teri certainly are interesting and exciting and provide some great twists, I really wonder how this makes any sense from the bad guys point of view.

To recall the plot:

Bauer's daughter **Kimberly** sneaks out at night to meet up with her friend and two guys to party. It turns out that they are actually planning to abduct Kimberly to force Bauer to help in the assassination of senator Palmer.

His wife **Teri** meets up with the father of Kimberly's friend to search for the two. Turns out he is actually a bad guy too, killed the real father and took his place to abduct Teri as well.

In retrospect, the whole plan seems far more complex than necessary to reach a very simple goal (abduction of daughter and wife). Also it unnecessarily relies on some coincidences.

- If the daughter had not snuck out of the house (either because she decided against it or because her parents caught her), the whole abduction plan would have failed. One of the guys has been dating her friend for some time before just to get Kimberly to meet them at that specific night.
- If the CTU did not get the tip about the planned assassination, Bauer would've been around that night to help Teri search for Kimberly. That would've made it a whole lot harder for the guy posing as the father to abduct Teri.
- Teri and the guy posing as the father chase behind the girls most of the night and even  make a 911 call when they find out they were abducted. That doesn't make a lot of sense, he could've just taken Teri at the start and save himself the whole trouble, also minimizing the risk of getting detected.
- The guys taking the girls are obviously amateurs, which makes it a lot more risky for the bad guys than just abducting Kimberly themselves.

**What stops the bad guys from simply taking Kimberly and Teri from their home?** They don't seem to have a problem with break-ins, after all they killed the father of Kimberly's friend that night, presumably at his home.

Is this just one of these "because the plot is more exciting this way" cases or is there any reasonable explanation why they make this whole elaborate plan to string Kimberly and Teri along all night before they finally abduct them?

Answer (score 3):

Later that same day between 1800 and 1900, when Teri has amnesia, her doctor friend takes her home. Upon entering and being unable to remember her security code, alarms begin to sound and within 2 minutes, armed security show up. I think it's safe to assume Nina told Gains about the alarm which forced the complicated abduction.

[image: Armed Guard 1]

[image: Armed Guard 2]

Comment: Good catch, this still leaves open the question why he did not abduct Teri at the first chance he got, but started the whole "Let's search for our daugthers!" odyseey. :)